# SonarQube не запускается на ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, sonarqube

Скрипт запуска Sonarqube не запускается на ubuntu 16.04

Журнал ошибок показывает:

```
Encountered an error running main: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: SonarQube requires Java 11+ to run**
java.lang.IllegalStateException: SonarQube requires Java 11+ to run
    at org.sonar.application.App.checkJavaVersion(App.java:93)
    at org.sonar.application.App.start(App.java:56)
    at org.sonar.application.App.main(App.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
<-- Wrapper Stopped
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Startup failed: Timed out waiting for a signal from the JVM.
JVM did not exit on request, terminated
JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Если я запускаю java -version:

```
java version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16 LTS
```

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS, mixed mode)

Может быть кто сталкивался с этим?

Comment: java-version в том же каталоге, откуда запускается sonar?

Comment: запуск команд из одного места

Answer (score 0):

решается добавлением пути к бинарнику java в /cont/wrapper.conf в опции 
wrapper.java.command

Например:

```
wrapper.java.command=/usr/bin/java
```